# MultiXactId has not been created yet -- apparent wraparound error in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

My team is confused as we are not doing anything then we experienced this in our staging environment. It's happening only in one of our tables. When we try fetch in that table, the message below returns

```
project=# SELECT * FROM table_table;
ERROR:  MultiXactId 24018 has not been created yet -- apparent wraparound
```

**UPDATE:**
Please take note that I am using docker containers and my image is `postgres:9.6.3-alpine`

Comment: You didn't state your PostgreSQL version. Is it recent? Did you `pg_upgrade` at some point? There have been a few bugs in this direction, compare [this](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=e3ad3ffa68193dd889a9cea9d840bf4613bd680b) and [that](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=423e1211a86df0d0dd8914223137edbfd4d52400) and read the [release notes for 9.5.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/release-9-5-4.html).

Comment: I updated my question. I'm using postgres 9.6.3 alpine image. I did not pg_upgrade

Comment: Can you `VACUUM (FREEZE)` the table?

Comment: It still returns `MultiXactId 24018 has not been created yet -- apparent wraparound`

Comment: It is either a PostgreSQL bug or data corruption.

Comment: How can I solve this besides deleting the table and just restoring via backup?

Comment: I don't know a different way. You could write to the PostgreSQL "general" mailing list.